# What Is the cumulative distribution function Of $Y = aX+b$ if $X\sim N(m,\sigma^2)$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

How do I calculate the cumulative distribution function of the random variable $$ Y = aX+b  $$  with $$ X\sim N(m,\sigma^2)$$ and $a,b\in\mathbb R$, $a\ne0$?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clarifying the elementary calculus used in this statistics problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1110917/clarifying-the-elementary-calculus-used-in-this-statistics-problem) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/806758/how-to-prove-something-at-normal-distribution)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $t\in\mathbb R$ we have for $a>0$
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(Y\leqslant t) &= \mathbb P(aX+b\leqslant  t)\\
&= \mathbb P\left(X\leqslant \frac{t-b}a\right)\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{(t-b)/a}\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} e^{-\frac12\left(\frac{x-m}{\sigma}\right)^2}\ \mathsf dx\\
&= \frac{1}{2}  \text{erfc}\left(\frac{ a m+b-t}{\sqrt{2\sigma^2} a}\right),
\end{align}
and for $a<0$
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(Y\leqslant t) &= \mathbb P\left(X\geqslant \frac{t-b}a\right)\\
&=\int_{(t-b)/a}^\infty\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} e^{-\frac12\left(\frac{x-m}{\sigma}\right)^2}\ \mathsf dx\\
&= \frac12\left(\text{erfi}\left(\frac{a m+b-t}{\sqrt{2} a \sigma }\right)-1\right).
\end{align}